# How can I delete the oldest n group of files with the same prefix?

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

In Linux I use InfluxDB which can make a backup of the database for archival purposes. Each backup comprises a series of files with the same prefix "/tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/20191225T235655Z." and different extensions.

I wanted to write a bash script which first deletes the oldest existing backups, then creates a new one (here I paste only the removal):

```
ls -tp /tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/* | grep -v '/$' | sed -E 's/\..+//' | \
  sort -ru | sed 's/$/.*/' | tail -n +4 | xargs -d '\n' -r rm --
```

However, when I run the script as "sudo", I get

```
rm: cannot remove '/tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/20191225T235655Z.*': No such file or directory
```

When I run the quoted script, except the latest part, I get:

```
/tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/20190930T215357Z.*
/tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/20190930T215352Z.*
```

which is correct. Also, if I manually write

```
sudo /tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/20190930T215357Z.*
```

the command succeeds.

Why is the script reporting an error?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and the folder "/tank" is a ZFS volume.

Comment: You may want to look into logrotate instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Robert I thought it is used for rotating logs. I want to backup the database

Answer (score 0):

Better do :

```
find /tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/* -mtime +5 -delete
```

to remove files older than 5 days.

Then, you can run the next command

Answer (score 0):

#### Explaining the Error

<sup>This answer is only here to explain the error and give a deeper understanding of what is happening. If you are simply looking for an elegant solution search for other answers.</sup>

> When I run the quoted script, except the latest part, I get:
>
> ```
> /tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/20190930T215357Z.*
> /tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/20190930T215352Z.*
> ```
>
> which is correct

The listed strings are not what you want. When you pass these paths to `rm` it sees them just as literal strings, that is, two files whose names end with a literal `*`. Since you don't have such files you get an error.

When you type `rm *` manually into your console `bash` (not `rm`!) does *globbing*. `bash` searches files and replaces the `*` with the list of found files. Only after that `bash` executes `rm foundFile1 foundFile2 ...`. `rm` never sees the `*`.

Strings inside a pipeline are not processed by `bash`, but by the commands in the pipeline, in your case `rm`. `rm` does not glob.

You could run `bash` inside your pipeline and let it expand the `*` you inserted earlier. To this end, replace the last command in your pipeline with `xargs -r bash -c 'rm -- $*' --`. However, note that your paths are not quoted here. If there are spaces or literal `*` in your filenames the command will break. This is necessary for globbing as quoted `"*"` are not expanded by `bash`.

To quote your files you have to insert the `*` glob inside the bash command:

```
ls -tp /tank/Backups/var/Influxdb/* | grep -v '/$' | sed -E 's/\..+//' |
sort -ru | tail -n +4 | xargs -d\\n -L1 -r bash -c 'rm -- "$0."*'
```

Above command is only a simple fix for your command. It is neither elegant nor very robust. Using tools like `find` is strongly recommended.